# How to find a coloured font from HTML and add it to parser?

Tags: python, json

I have a code that parses information about competitions from the RSСF website. Yes, yes, parsing again. But don't worry, I already know what and how. And wrote the code. It works like clockwork for me. Doesn't give any errors.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
from urllib.parse import unquote

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

BASE_URL = 'https://www.rscf.ru/contests'

session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0'

items = []
max_page = 10
for page in range(1, max_page + 1):
    url = f'{BASE_URL}/?PAGEN_2={page}/' if page > 1 else BASE_URL
    print(url)

    rs = session.get(url, verify=False)
    rs.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.select('.classification-table-row.contest-table-row'):
        number = item.select_one('.contest-num').text
        title = item.select_one('.contest-name').text
        date = item.select_one('.contest-date').text.replace("\n", "").replace("Подать заявку", "")
        documents = item.select_one('.contest-docs').text.replace("\n", " ").replace("        ", " ").replace("    ", " ")
        synopsis = item.select_one('.contest-status').text.replace("\n", " ")
        items.append({
            'Номер': number,
            'Наименование конкурса': title,
            'Приём заявок': date,
            'Статус': synopsis,
            'Документы': documents,
        })

with open('out.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(items, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Everything works, everything is in order. There is one nuance.

The fact is that the site has such a feature - the color of the text. Depending on whether the competition is active or completed, the status is colored in a certain color. If applications are being accepted, the status is highlighted in green. If an examination is carried out - orange. And if the contest is over - red. Here are the contests.

https://www.rscf.ru/contests/
And I need the code to output in JSON the text that is marked in red, orange or green in HTML. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything similar on the Internet. There are only codes that color the text in color. But do not extract ready.

I tried to write a code

```
redword = item.select_one('.contest-danger').text
        orangeword = item.select_one('.contest-danger').text
        greenword = item.select_one('.contest-success').text
        for synopsis in item.select_one('.contest-status').text:
            try:
                syn = re.sub(orangeword, str(synopsis))
            except:
                syn = re.sub(orangeword, str(greenword))
        items.append({
            'Номер': number,
            'Наименование конкурса': title,
            'Приём заявок': date,
            'Статус': syn,
            'Документы': documents,
        })
```

but it gave me only error

```
redword = item.select_one('.contest-danger').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: check `element.style.color` attribute

Comment: But that attrbibute is used on JavaScript, not on Python.

Comment: follow my answer, you can get the color value from the style property array/dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the color here

Here is the long explanation.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Assume 'html' is your HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Use a CSS selector to target the desired element
element = soup.select_one('h1')  # Replace 'h1' with your target selector

# Check if the element exists
if element:
    # Get the 'style' attribute of the element
    style = element.get('style')
    # Parse the 'style' attribute to extract the color
    if style:
        # Split the 'style' attribute into individual styles
        styles = style.split(';')
        # Search for the 'color' style
        for style in styles:
            if 'color' in style:
                # Extract the color value
                color = style.split(':')[1].strip()
                print("Color:", color)
else:
    print("Element not found.")
```

Short version

```py
title = item.select_one('.contest-name')
style = title.get('style')

if style:
    # Split the style into individual styles
    styles = style.split(';')

    # Search for the color style
    for style in styles:
        if 'color' in style:
            # Extract the color value
            color = style.split(':')[1].strip()
            print("Color:", color)
else:
    print("Style attribute not found.")
```

Comment: Especially, I don't need a print of style. I need print word that has a style. Also it mustn't be in console. It must be in JSON.

Comment: @GaloGalo that was just an example, just do something with the `color` variable

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided to write the next code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
from urllib.parse import unquote

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

BASE_URL = 'https://www.rscf.ru/contests'

session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0'

items = []
max_page = 10
for page in range(1, max_page + 1):
    url = f'{BASE_URL}/?PAGEN_2={page}/' if page > 1 else BASE_URL
    print(url)

    rs = session.get(url, verify=False)
    rs.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.select('.classification-table-row.contest-table-row'):
        number = item.select_one('.contest-num').text
        title = item.select_one('.contest-name').text
        date = item.select_one('.contest-date').text.replace("\n", "").replace("Подать заявку", "")
        documents = item.select_one('.contest-docs').text.replace("\n", " ").replace("        ", " ").replace("    ", " ")
        try:
            synopsis = [s.get_text(strip=True) for s in item.select(".contest-status") if s.get_text(strip=True)]
            del synopsis[:1]
            syn = str(synopsis).replace("['", '').replace("']", '')
        except:
            synopsis = [s.get_text(strip=True) for s in item.select(".contest-success") if s.get_text(strip=True)]
            del synopsis[:1]
            syn = str(synopsis).replace("['", '').replace("']", '')
        items.append({
            'Номер': number,
            'Наименование конкурса': title,
            'Приём заявок': date,
            'Статус': syn,
            'Документы': documents,
        })

with open('out.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(items, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Result is:

```
{
        "Номер": "92",
        "Наименование конкурса": " Конкурс на получение грантов РНФ по мероприятию «Проведение фундаментальных научных исследований и поисковых научных исследований отдельными научными группами»",
        "Приём заявок": "до 15.11.2023 17:00",
        "Статус": "Прием заявок",
        "Документы": " Извещение Конкурсная документация    "
    },
    {
        "Номер": "3005",
        "Наименование конкурса": "Конкурс на получение грантов РНФ «Проведение пилотных проектов НИОКР в рамках стратегических инициатив Президента РФ в научно-технологической сфере» по теме: «Разработка нитрид-галлиевого СВЧ-транзистора S-диапазона с выходной мощностью не менее 120 Вт»",
        "Приём заявок": "до 02.06.2023 17:00",
        "Статус": "Конкурс завершен",
        "Документы": " Извещение Конкурсная документация Список победителей "
    },
    {
```

You can try it by yourself